# Nodemailer with Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, smtp

I'm trying to send some emails from a docker container running express through register365.

This is the code used

```
export class Emailer {
transporter: nodemailer.Transporter;
constructor() {
    this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        host: 'smtp.reg365.net',
        auth: {
            user: 'myuser',
            pass: mypassword'
        }
    }));
}

public async sendEmail(to,body) {
    try {
        return await this.transporter.sendMail({to,from: '"TEST" <user@myuser.ie>',text: body, subject: ' WE NEED THE CONTENT AND DESIGN OF THIS EMAIL!!!!'});
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log('Email error');
        console.dir(error);
    }

}
}
```

That's working all fine if I run the express with npm start but If I run it with docker it'll fail with this error `Error: Connection closed`

It only fails using smtp.reg.356.net, if I use Gmail it'll work perfectly

This is the docker file I'm using

```
FROM  node:8

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

COPY ./dist /usr/src/app/dist

EXPOSE 3005
EXPOSE 25
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Many thanks.

EDIT:
As requested, running telnet smtp.reg365.net 25 returns this `telnet: could not resolve smtp.reg.356.net/25: Name or service not known`

Output of cat /etc/resolv.conf on the host machine

```
domain Hitronhub.home
nameserver 89.101.160.5
nameserver 89.101.160.4
```

On the docker container

```
search hitronhub.home
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

Comment: Launch the container and go into a bash shell. Execute the command `telnet smtp.reg.356.net 25` and post the output in your question

Comment: Done, this is the output telnet: could not resolve smtp.reg.356.net/25: Name or service not known. Thanks

Comment: One more `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on both the host machine and inside the docker container. Most probably it is a dns setting that you need. I will write the answer once I confirm that is the issue

Comment: Done, it's on the answer as an edit. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
"dns": ["89.101.160.5", "89.101.160.4"]
}
```

Restart the docker service and try again and see if this works for you.

You are probably on office network which has its own DNS servers that you should be using. So you need to tell the Docker daemon which DNS server its containers should be using. That is what is creating the issue. The `daemon.json` file can be used to change the daemon configuration.

Comment: That solved the issue, thank you!
Would you mind explaining to me what was the issue?

Comment: Updated the answer, see if that explanation helps?